# connecting to a HPC machine via a third party machine and file transfer

Tags: server, ssh

I have to connect to a HPC machine (server) at work from my home for some reasons including saving data or running analysis. to do so first I have to connect to a third party HPC machine using ssh command and then connect to the main HPC machine I want to work on again using ssh command. actually I can connect through this way but I can not copy data there. do you know copy data to the main HPC from my home?
here is the way I follow to connect to the main HPC machine:

```
ssh bjackson@bal.wur.nl

ssh bjackson@issac
```

issac is the name of the main HPC machine.

Comment: I reverted the edit that defaced the entire question. If you want to edit your own posts please do so with your original account so it doesn't have to go through review. However, please *don't* ”edit out” your own (or anybody's) question because it was resolved (or for any reason really). AskUbuntu is no forum and we'd like to keep posts around if they may be useful to future readers. If your question became moot for some reason you can flag it for closure as off topic or for moderator attention with a short comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect use the *ProxyCommand* of SSH, which then automatically does the hop and you can use `ssh bjackson@issac` or `scp file.txt bjackson@issac:/tmp` for example.

Add the following to your *~/.ssh/config*.

```
Host isaac
    Hostname isaac
    Port 22
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bjackson@bal.wur.nl
```